# How do I subtract 1 from a label "26" everytime a button is pressed? (Swift Beginner)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10.1

Swift Beginner

I want to subtract 1 from a label with value "26" every time the "deal" button is pressed. Do I convert it to an Int? And how do I add calculations to it?

I coded cardsAmount.text = "25", which works. But it needs to subtract 1 every time the button is pressed and not assign a hardcoded value.

Also, in the future I would like to add to the number.

Thanks!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var leftPile: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var rightPile: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var cardsAmount: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        }


    @IBAction func deal(_ sender: Any) {

        let shuffled = (2...53).shuffled()
        let leftNumber = shuffled[0]
        let rightNumber = shuffled[1]

        //cardsAmount.text = "25"

        leftPile.image = UIImage(named: "c\(leftNumber)")

        rightPile.image = UIImage(named: "c\(rightNumber)")


    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use property observer.

```
var number: Int = 26 {
    didSet {
        if number > 0 {
        self.cardsAmount.text = "\(number)"
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func deal(_ sender: Any) {
    let shuffled = (2...53).shuffled()
    let leftNumber = shuffled[0]
    let rightNumber = shuffled[1]

    number -= 1 // whenever number value changes, didSet (property observer) will be called

    leftPile.image = UIImage(named: "c\(leftNumber)")
    rightPile.image = UIImage(named: "c\(rightNumber)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a `variable` as you are a beginner. Use this:

```
var initialNumber: Int = 1
var number: Int = 26

@IBAction func deal(_ sender: Any) {

    let shuffled = (2...53).shuffled()
    let leftNumber = shuffled[0]
    let rightNumber = shuffled[1]

    number = number - initialNumber
    cardsAmount.text = "\(number)" //This is to subtract. Now you can check if it is a negative number and perform operations ahead using if else

    leftPile.image = UIImage(named: "c\(leftNumber)")

    rightPile.image = UIImage(named: "c\(rightNumber)")


}
```

You can follow the same approach to add a number. If you want to save the `initialNumber` then you can write `initialNumber = initialNumber + 1` and then use it. Do let me know if you have any query regarding this answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hasty response, but i need it to subtract 1 every time the button is pressed, at the moment it only does it once, thanks

Comment: @ssdd2010 Updated the answer. Although, you do not need `initialNumber` now, but just for your learning experience, I am keeping it there. Do let me know if you have any query.

Comment: This works, and i see how i can just change to number = number - 1 and delete the initial number variable. How do i show my Appreciation ? do i just upvote your answer and is that all i can do?

Comment: @ssdd2010 You can mark this answer as correct if it works. This way any other person with the same query will rely confidently on this answer. Also, just a quick tip, you can also write `number = number -1 as the number -= 1`. This does the same thing. Do let me know if you still have any query, otherwise mark it as correct.